# Не находить id с строки get запроса node(express)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

Привет!Я хотел сделать свой небольшой API сервер на NODE.js но столкнулся с проблемой что сервер не видит переменную id с строки запроса и я постоянно получаю код с `else{...}`.

```
router.get('/:id',(req,res,next)=>{
    const id = req.param.id;
    if (id === 'special') {
        res.status(200).json({
            message: 'You discover the special Id',
            id : id
        });
    }else{
            res.status(200).json({
                message: '',
                id: id
            });
        }
    }
);
```

Можете подсказать как это исправить?

Comment: А что он видит вместо переменной?

Comment: Ничего!я получаю ответ `{message : ''}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Привет.
У тебя опечатка в коде:

```
 const id = req.param.id;
```

Должно быть:

```
 const id = req.params.id;
```

Блока req.param не существует.

Рейтинга нет в комментарий написать)

Comment: Спасибо!Я уже думал експресс битый скачал:)

Answer (score -1):

У вас опечатка при получении ID (вторая строка, там должно быть paramS). попробуйте

```
const id = req.params.id;
```